# How to show loading image with progress bar and image also want to counting number in my gridview andriod studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gridview

I have created android app like gallery which have some images using gridview fragment.

Functionality of my application is working fine and image showing in fragment gridview and also my second activity open when i click on item but i want to show loading image with progress bar when my image not load or take time for loading complete.

Also i want to show image counting number in gridview.

But i want to progress bar on loading images like this : [WANT LINK THIS SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSbmw.png)

My gridview looks like this : [My gridview looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiBLm.png)

already to find the 
Here is my application fragment code :

```
    public class CallFragment extends Fragment {

GridView grid;
        String[] plan = {
                "Student Bundle",
                "SMS Plus Bundle",
                "Instagram",
                "Facebook",
                "Flickr"

        } ;
        String[] web = {
                "*3000",
                "*106*1",
                "Instagram",
                "Facebook",
                "Flickr"

        } ;
        int[] imageId = {
                R.drawable.calla,
                R.drawable.smsb,
                R.drawable.person7,
                R.drawable.person7,
                R.drawable.person7

        };
        int[] fullimg = {
                R.drawable.callaa,
                R.drawable.smsbb,
                R.drawable.person7,
                R.drawable.person7,
                R.drawable.person7

        };

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_call,container,false);

            CustomGrid adapter = new CustomGrid(getActivity(), plan, web, imageId, fullimg);

            grid=(GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid);
            grid.setAdapter(adapter);
            grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    String value=(String)grid.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),Book.class);
                    intent.putExtra("web", web[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("plan", plan[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("imageId", imageId[i]);
                    intent.putExtra("fullimg", fullimg[i]);
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            return view;
        }
```

Here is my application CustomAdapter code :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> personNames;
    ArrayList<String> personCode;
    ArrayList<Integer> personImages;
    ArrayList<Integer> personImages1;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> personNames, ArrayList<String> personCode, ArrayList<Integer> personImages, ArrayList<Integer> personImages1) {
        this.context = context;
        this.personCode = personCode;
        this.personNames = personNames;
        this.personImages = personImages;
        this.personImages1 = personImages1;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // infalte the item Layout
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v); // pass the view to View Holder
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        // set the data in items
        //holder.name.setText(personNames.get(position));
        holder.image.setImageResource(personImages.get(position));
        //holder.image.setImageResource(personImages1.get(position));
        // implement setOnClickListener event on item view.
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // open another activity on item click
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);
                //intent.putExtra("image", personImages.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                intent.putExtra("name", personNames.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                intent.putExtra("code", personCode.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                intent.putExtra("image", personImages1.get(position)); // put image data in Intent
                context.startActivity(intent); // start Intent
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return personNames.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // init the item view's
        TextView name;
        TextView code;
        ImageView image;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            // get the reference of item view's
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            code = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.code);
            image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        }
    }
}
```

Also if it is easier default image in place of loading images instead of progress bar will be fine.

Please provide me solution to implement this.
i hope you get my main point which i want and Thanks for help.